# Change font-size of <v-radio> vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am newly using vuetify. I want to change font-size of `<v-radio>` button and its label. Directly applying css not working. So i searched for some answer, but those answer are very short. Which i'm unable to apply them. Can anyone help me to explain how do i change font-size in vuetify? TIA

Updated:

```
<template>
<v-flex xs6>
    <p class="title-input">Jenis Kelamin</p>
    <v-radio-group id="id-gender" class="no-space" v-model="genderSelect" :mandatory="false" row @change="genderAction">
       <v-radio class="gender" label="Pria" value="Pria"></v-radio>
       <v-radio class="gender" label="Wanita" value="Wanita"></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
    <span class="text-error" v-show="genderError">Mohon diisi</span>
</v-flex>
</template>

<style scoped src="../style/Shortform.css">

</style>
```

Comment: Can you share some code which didn't work?

Comment: updated to question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer. In my css file all i have to do is

```
.customClass >>> label
```

adding those >>> icon solved the problem.

Comment: do you mean writing CSS :    .gender >>> label  in you case ?

Comment: now with ::v-deep for example:

.blue--text::v-deep label {
    color: #1976d2;
}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a style tag in the `.vue` file you have the option to remove `scoped` from the style tag and target the label directly.

```
<style>
  .v-label {
    font-size: desired size
  }
</style>
```

If it happens that you have a separate `.css` file you can still use this method and ignore the `<style>` tag

```
.v-label {
  font-size: desired size
}
```

Comment: be careful doing this as it is going to override the vuetify class globally, not just in your component. A good way to manage this is to hook into it with a  container class, so `<style>
  #myComponent .v-label {
    font-size: desired size
  }
</style>` so as to not accidentally override styles in other components

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
.small-radio i {
  font-size: 19px;
}
.small-radio label {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.small-radio .v-radio {
  padding: 0px;
}
.small-radio [class*="__ripple"] {
  left: 0;
}
```

Add `v-deep::` infront if requred.

Add the style to `v-radio-group`:

```
<v-radio-group class="small-radio" v-model="radioGroup">
   <v-radio
    ...
   ></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```